# Multiplication-like binary operator based on Maclaurin series of functions

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, operator-theory, taylor-expansion, binary-operations

Let us define the binary function operator $\maltese$ based on the Maclaurin series of real-valued functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$:
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(0)\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\maltese\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g^{(n)}(0)\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=f \operatorname{\maltese} g=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g^{(n)}(0)\cdot f^{(n)}(0)\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Some obvious properties of the $\maltese$ operator:
$$f\operatorname{\maltese}g=g\operatorname{\maltese}f$$
$$(f\operatorname{\maltese}g)\operatorname{\maltese}h=f\operatorname{\maltese}(g\operatorname{\maltese}h)$$
$$(f+g)\operatorname{\maltese}h=f\operatorname{\maltese}h+g\operatorname{\maltese}h$$
$$(C\cdot f)\operatorname{\maltese}g=C\cdot(f\operatorname{\maltese}g)\quad(C=\mathrm{const})$$
$$f\operatorname{\maltese}0=0$$
$$f\operatorname{\maltese}\exp=f$$
$$\sin\operatorname{\maltese}\cos=0$$
Has such operator been described or studied anywhere? Do we know any non-trivial properties of the $\maltese$ operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often called the [Hadamard product of a power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product) and certainly has been studied. It is closely related to the [Cartesian product operation on combinatorial species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species#Further_operations). There are many other applications, of course.